# Search for a word, and modify the whole line in Python text processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-processing

This is my carDatabase.txt

```
CarID:c01   ModelName:honda VehicleType:city    Price:20
CarID:c02   ModelName:honda VehicleType:x   Price:30
```

I want to search for the carID and be only able to modify the whole line without interrupting others

my current code is here:

```
# Converting txt data into a string and modify
carsDatabaseFile = open('carsDatabase.txt', 'r')
allDataFromDatabase = [line.split(',') for line in carsDatabaseFile.readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note:
Your question has a couple of issues: your sample from carDatabase.txt looks like it is tab-delimited, but your current code looks like it is splitting the line around the ',' character.  This also looks like a place where a list comprehension might be hurting you more than it is helping you. Break that up into a for-loop if you're trying to add some logic to manipulate a single line.

For looking at CSV files, I would highly recommend using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html#getting-started) for general manipulation of data in comma ceparated as well as a number of other formats.

That said, if you are truly restricted to only using built-in packages, or you are looking at this as a learning exercise, and your goal is to directly manipulate just one line of that file, what you are looking for is the [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) method.  You can use this in combination with the tell method ( documented just blow seek in the above link ) to find where you are in the file.

1. Write a for loop to identify which line in the file you are looking for
2. From there, you can get the output of [tell](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell)() to find the specific place in the file you are trying to manipulate
3. Using the output from the above two steps, you can set the file pointer to a specific location using the [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)() method (by byte: files are really stored as one dimensional).
4. You can now use the [write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write)() method to directly update the file at the location you determined above.